# Is badge harvesting possible?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I've come across this question:

[How can I get the current class of a div with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536117/75642)

that gained an enormous amount of views (earning the guy a golden badge) for it. I expect the amount of views was generated purely because the question was so simple that everyone wanted to contribute...

**What bothers me though is** that this person that originally asked the question has a **silver jQuery badge** themselves and I would never expect such a question from a person with that badge.

This raises a question:

### Do tag badges have any value?

I don't care about other badges that much since they have stackoverflow community value only, but tag badges have a kind of real-life value related to it. **Are my assumptions false?**

### What seems the issue here?

It seems that this person that should have sufficient jQuery knowledge, asked a very general ans simple question that resulted in lots of views getting him a golden (non tag) badge... Do we want this? Can it be prevented?

Comment: The question was asked 2 years ago, perhaps the question asker has since learned to use jQuery properly?

Comment: Tag badges are crazy hard to get for the most part...so I'd say they have more "value" relative to the "value" of other badges; they represent as much or more effort than pretty much any other badge. Not sure what relevance that question has to the situation though, tag badges are for answers. All the "dumb" questions in the world won't get you one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's true. I got a bit confused by the fact that *Famous Question* badge itself was rewarded recently... But this likely has to do with the age of the question. But that also raises a different question: Being a member for long enough will give your golden badges anyway. It's like saying **every old wine will have high value and the older it is the higher it will get**. Which is of course not true.

Comment: If it gets a lot of views isn't that an indication that it is a useful resource lots of people search for? What does it matter what the motivation of the asker is?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik If a bunch of people are clamoring to drink the wine, then yes, it's value is high. Also alcohol, to a reasonable point, almost exclusively increases in value with age, proper storage permitting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question was asked nearly 3 years ago, perhaps the question asker has since learned to use jQuery properly?

And in my opinion any tag badge has no actual value real-world value beyond Stack Overflow, at least not without checking the quality of individual answers *and* checking the size of the community that *votes* on those tags. A silver badge for a low answer count in a obscure tag is more 'valuable' than such a badge for a popular topic with a high answer count.

The person in question earned their 510 upvotes for the tag with 480 answers. Make of that what you will.

As for the golden badge for views, that's because a lot of people viewed the question, and has nothing to do whatsoever with the motivations of the asker. His question is popular (a lot of *other* people obviously are interested in the answer to the question).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I was jumping my conclusions too quickly. But I don't agree with you that badges don't have any real-world value. Of course they do. You should watch [this TED video](http://www.ted.com/talks/rachel_botsman_the_currency_of_the_new_economy_is_trust.html) that speaks in my favour and is very relevant to SO badges. And believe me. My SO badges also contributed to my current job position (because I did put them in my CV). What other proof do you need of badge real-life value? ;)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: If you are attaching values to badges, then first verify how the badge was earned. If I were to pepper the `C++` tag with half-informed answers, I might get a badge as well. That doesn't make me a C++ expert.

Comment: That's true, but 99% of people will not abuse the system this way.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Always check for the actual value provided in their answers.

Comment: In the vast majority tag badges are valuable and related to actual person's knowledge. That was likely one of the main reasons to have them in the first place.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Sure, I am proud of each and every tag badge I hold. I just have also seen plenty of tag badges awarded where the recipient's answer-to-upvote ratio leaves a lot to be desired..

Comment: Minor nitpick: the question is 3 years old not 2 (asked **2009**-10-08)

Comment: @RalZarek: right, I was going by the relative date display, which isn't too precise; corrected my answer just for you. :-)

Comment: These were my first C#/.NET questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778109/standard-windows-menu-bars-in-windows-forms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907420/is-there-a-need-to-convert-a-visual-studio-express-solution-to-a-visual-studio-p I now have a gold [c#] badge, with a score-answer ratio of more than 6, and I have no clue why or how.